# How to create a permanent accordion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found this [Bootstrap Accordion Link](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Pajeb). It is working fine to add new div accordion. But my problem here is after I refresh the page it back to normal. I try to apply this code to mine to see what is the effect.

It is possible to add a permanent div accordion?.

I plan to do this accordion because I have a `File Maintenance` for the `Positions` like `Senators , President.. etc`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var counter = 1;
  var wrapper = $("#accordion");

  $("#addButton").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var catgName = prompt("Please Add your category name");
    if (catgName == '') {
      catgName = 'Catg#' + counter;
    }
    if (catgName != null) {
      var ariaExpanded = false;
      var expandedClass = '';
      var collapsedClass = 'collapsed';
      if (counter == 1) {
        ariaExpanded = true;
        expandedClass = 'in';
        collapsedClass = '';
      }
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 0;"><div class="panel panel-default" id="panel' + counter + '">' +
        '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading' + counter + '"><h4 class="panel-title">' +
        '<a class="' + collapsedClass + '" id="panel-lebel' + counter + '" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse' + counter + '" ' +
        'aria-expanded="' + ariaExpanded + '" aria-controls="collapse' + counter + '"> ' + catgName + ' </a><div class="actions_div" style="position: relative; top: -26px;">' +
        '<a href="#" accesskey="' + counter + '" class="remove_ctg_panel exit-btn pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>' +
        '<a href="#" accesskey="' + counter + '" class="edit_ctg_label pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit "></span> Edit</a>' +
        '<a href="#" accesskey="' + counter + '" class="pull-right" id="addButton2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add child category</a></div></h4></div>' +
        '<div id="collapse' + counter + '" class="panel-collapse collapse ' + expandedClass + '"role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading' + counter + '">' +
        '<div class="panel-body"><div id="TextBoxDiv' + counter + '"></div><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" accesskey="' + counter + '" id="addButton3" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Attributes</a>' +
        '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" accesskey="' + counter + '" id="ajax_submit_button" >Done</a></div></div></div></div>');
      counter++;
    }

  });

  var x = 1;
  $(wrapper).on("click", "#addButton2", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var parentId = $(this).attr('accesskey');
    var parentPanel = '#panel' + parentId;
    var catgName = prompt("Please Add your category name");
    if (catgName == '') {
      catgName = ' P#' + parentId + ' Catg#' + counter;
    }
    if (catgName != null) {
      var ariaExpanded = false;
      var expandedClass = '';
      var collapsedClass = 'collapsed';

      $(wrapper).find(parentPanel).append('<div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 0;"><div class="panel panel-default" id="panel' + counter + '">' +
        '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="heading' + counter + '"><h4 class="panel-title">' +
        '<a class="' + collapsedClass + '" id="panel-lebel' + counter + '" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse' + counter + '" ' +
        'aria-expanded="' + ariaExpanded + '" aria-controls="collapse' + counter + '"> ' + catgName + ' </a><div class="actions_div" style="position: relative; top: -26px;">' +
        '<a href="#" accesskey="' + counter + '" class="remove_ctg_panel exit-btn pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>' +
        '<a href="#" accesskey="' + counter + '" class="edit_ctg_label pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit</a>' +
        '<a href="#" accesskey="' + counter + '" class="pull-right" id="addButton2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add child category</a></h4></div>' +
        '<div id="collapse' + counter + '" class="panel-collapse collapse ' + expandedClass + '"role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading' + counter + '">' +
        '<div class="panel-body"><div id="TextBoxDiv' + counter + '"></div><a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" accesskey="' + counter + '" id="addButton3" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Attributes</a>' +
        '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success" accesskey="' + counter + '" id="ajax_submit_button" >Done</a></div></div></div></div>');

      x++;
      counter++;
    }

  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_ctg_panel", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var accesskey = $(this).attr('accesskey');
    $('#panel' + accesskey).remove();
    counter--;
    x--;
  });




  var y = 1;
  $(wrapper).on("click", "#addButton3", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var accesskey = $(this).attr('accesskey');
    y++;
    $('#panel' + accesskey).find('#TextBoxDiv' + accesskey).append('<div class="col-md-12 form-group"><input type="text" name="ctgtext[]" class="form-control" style="width: 40%;float: left;"/><a href="#" class="remove_field exit-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></a></div>');

  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    y--;
  })

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".edit_ctg_label", function(e) {
    var panelId = $(this).attr('accesskey');
    var catgName = prompt("Please Change your category name");
    if (catgName == '') {
      return false;
    }
    if (catgName != null) {
      $('#panel' + panelId).find("#panel-lebel" + panelId).html('').html(catgName);
    }


  });
});
```

```css
#accordion .panel-heading {
  padding: 0;
}
#accordion .panel-title>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
  outline: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion .panel-title>a.accordion-toggle::before,
#accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
  content: "\e113";
  float: left;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#accordion .panel-title>a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before,
#accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::before {
  content: "\e114";
}
#accordion.panel-group .panel {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#accordion .actions_div > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#accordion .actions_div > a.exit-btn {
  color: #dd4b39;
}
#accordion .remove_field.exit-btn {
  color: #dd4b39;
  margin-left: 7px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <!-- Horizontal Form -->
    <div class="panel panel-success">
      <div class="panel-header with-border">
        <h2 class="panel-title text-center">Add Category</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-header -->
      <!-- form start -->
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="panel-body">

          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="margin-top:15px;">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="addButton" value=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New Field</button>
          </div>


        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
        <div class="panel-footer">
          <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 text-center">

          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer -->
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `back to normal ` & `It is possible to add a permanent div accordion?.`

Comment: @user2181397 what I mean in `back to normal` is. I got already a accordion (1 accordion) and I use this code to add new accordions. After refresh the page it goes back to normal `1 accordion`. In permanent div accordion is. It won't never disappear.

Comment: I dont think that will be possible. This is  because you are creating accordion with one data. when you update you have the new accordion, but no where it is save. What yuoou hvae to do is that once you update store the value somewhere. Then create the accordion depending on  number of the value length

Comment: @user2181397 can you show some example?. I am new to this.